# Cant install pip modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.
py", line 216, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.p
y", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\install.
py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy
\resolver.py", line 183, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy
\resolver.py", line 388, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy
\resolver.py", line 340, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\operations\prepar
e.py", line 467, in prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\operations\prepar
e.py", line 255, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\operations\prepar
e.py", line 129, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\operations\prepar
e.py", line 282, in _download_http_url
    for chunk in download.chunks:
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars
.py", line 172, in iter
    self.next(len(x))  # noqa: B305
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\progress\__init__.p
y", line 120, in next
    self.update()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\progress\bar.py", l
ine 83, in update
    self.writeln(line)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\progress\__init__.p
y", line 100, in writeln
    if self.file and self.is_tty():
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\progress\__init__.p
y", line 112, in is_tty
    return self.file.isatty() if self.check_tty else True
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj3_890qp\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars
.py", line 200, in <lambda>
    self.file.isatty = lambda: self.file.wrapped.isatty()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isatty'
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2; however, version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Everytime I try to install anything with `pip` this error tends to show up. I tried to reinstall `pip` with `get-pip.py` from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py even for this I get the same error.

I am running python 3.8.5 and pip 20.2.

Comment: Can you show how you are running the `get-pip.py` file?

Comment: i executed it as normal python script  `python get-pip.py`